# Show that the Compact open topology on Hom(X,Y) is hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology

I am trying to complete this topological question and I would like to know if my solution is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Solution:

Let X be a topological space, and Y a Hausdorff topological space. Now, let f,g $\in$ Hom(X,Y) be such that f $\neq$ g. Then, there $\exists$ $x$$_o$$\in$ $x$ such that f($x$$_o$)$\neq$ g($x$$_o$). Since Y is Hausdorff, there $\exists$ open neighborhoods U of f($x$$_o$) and V of g($x$$_o$) such that U$\cap$V=$\emptyset$. Then, f $\in$ S({$x$$_o$},U) and g $\in$ S({$x$$_o$},V). Also, S({$x$$_o$},U) $\cap$ S({$x$$_o$},V) = $\emptyset$, becuase if h $\in$ S({$x$$_o$},U) $\cap$ S({$x$$_o$},V), then h($x$$_o$) $\in$ U and h($x$$_o$) $\in$ V. Since, U $\cap$ V = $\emptyset$, this implies that h maps $x$$_o$ into two distinct points. Thus we have a contradiction. Therefore, Hom(X,Y) is Hausdorff with the compact open topology.

Comment: You didn't write any of the assumptions on $X,Y$ into the body of the text. Please include the full question. What is $S$? Also, why is this tagged algebraic topology?

Comment: The full question is the title. And it is tagged algebraic topology because that is the section from which this question came from in my book. S is a subset of the interior of points of the topology X

Comment: How can the full question be in the title when you haven't written the assumption that $Y$ is Hausdorff anywhere? It's generally good practice to restate your question in the body-text together with  all of the assumptions needed.

Comment: I did state that Y is Hausdorff in my solution. It is right in the very first line. "Let X be a topological space, and Y a Hausdorff topological space."

Comment: in your solution...but not in the "full question" which is in the title. This seems to not be a productive conversation at all. I don't understand all the resistance that I am getting.

Comment: I am just trying to explain that the question which is in the book is literally word for word what I put in the title "Show that the compact-open topology on Hom(X,Y) is Hausdorff". There was nothing more to the question. Which is why I put that in my solution that Y is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!